# Create an If statement comparing a custom field MS Word

Tags: if-statement, ms-word

I'm trying to create an if statement (in MS Word) that looks at a custom field.

The custom field is DocProperty Client_ABV

I want it to print a line of text if client_abv matches a certain value else be completely blank (or delete the empty line if possible)

I believe it needs to look something like this:

{IF DocProperty.Client_ABV="Test" "Print this line if Test",""}

I've very little experience with this function in Word but I have some with conditional programming.

Can anyone shed any light. I've been googling it for the last 45 minutes and have had little success with the example pages I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ctrl+F9 to insert the field code { brackets }. They look like wavy brackets, but these are actually special "escape codes" that tell Word this is a field code.

You need a pair of brackets for *both* the IF and the DocProperty fields.

When performing a string comparison it's a good idea to put "quotes" around the field code as well as around the literal string.

There is no punctuation in the DocProperty field code (no period). And no comma between the true/false evaluation, only a space between the closing " and opening ".

If a paragraph mark should be part of the true/false evaluation (for example, you want to suppress the paragraph mark if the comparison is false) include it *inside* the "quotes" for the evaluation result. The field code will look a bit odd, but that does work.

For example:

```
{ IF "{ DocProperty Client_ABV }"="Test" "Print this line if Test¶
" ""}
```

Comment: Although this is rather weird, I had no other way of massaging you :) Would you at all be able to comment or assist with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986922/update-or-refresh-word-contentcontrols You've helped tons in the past, so I thought it worth while asking.