# Update or refresh Word ContentControls

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-interop

I have a scenario whereby I need to (programmatically) add `ContextControls` to a `Word` table.

My example is when a user adds a `ContentControl` to a table (first cell) then adds a repeating `ContentControl` to that row - this is perfect!

If the user then goes to cell 2 of a 2 cell table (to keep things simple) and adds another `ContentControl` - keeping in mind this row is already a repeating `ContentControl` and now just has an additional `ContentControl` added, the data does not repeat.

If I go into my `Word` ribbon - Developer, then flick design on and off, the data all appears fine again (almost like the repeating `ContentControl` was updated / refreshed). I'm wondering - is there a way to do this through code?

Something like repeating ContentControl.Update / Refresh / Reload (none of those exist).

Right now - I'll even accept if I can do this through the `Word` application itself, but I will be converting this to code.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If the user adds a new row to the repeating content control, isn't he/she supposed to also enter the data? Can you explain what data should appear in the newly added row?

Comment: @DirkVollmar Thanks for the comment, I can see the confusion, I have updated the image, which will hopefully help? Basically the user adds a new table, the a single contentcontrol to the first cell, then selects the entire table row and makes it a repeating control (hence, the first cell repeats). Then they go into the 2nd cell of the first row and add another single contentcontrol (thinking it will automatically become a repeating item) but it doesn't, not until that design is activated / de-activated.

Comment: PS - I've noticed that one way of doing this is to manually toggle `ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign`, was wondering if it's the best way?

Comment: I wasn't able to repro. For me, the content control added to the second column also gets repeated in the new row. Maybe this is related to the particular document you are having or the particular Word version you are using.

Comment: The repo steps to try... Open a document that has 2 items within a customxmlpart, add a single row table, with two cells. Within the first column, add a child from the first item of the xmlpart, then select the entire row and add that parent item as a repeating content control. Now select a different child from the item and place it as a content control in the 2nd column. The first column should have two completed rows, the second column should only have the first?? I'm using 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone needing the answer to this:

After 3 days, I've decided that the best way to accomplish this task, is by calling the `.ToggleFormsDesign` method twice.

This will basically "refresh / update" the binding on the repeating ContentControl

```
        With ActiveDocument
            .ToggleFormsDesign
            .ToggleFormsDesign
        End With
```

Calling this method back to back, will have no UI / visual impact (i.e. the user will not notice anything).

[MSDN Link to the Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195394.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)