# Why does MS Word's DOCPROPERTY not recognize a document property field from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, word-field

I'm using SharePoint to generate a MS Word document. The data comes through to the template from SharePoint as document properties. I am able to have the data appear in the generated document. What I would like to do is use a field to do some formatting based on the presence or absence of data in the document property field. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971372/create-an-if-statement-comparing-a-custom-field-ms-word) which uses DOCPROPERTY custom_field as the first part of the comparison. However, the document property I want to use is not recognized despite showing up in the document property list under insert quick parts.[image: Quick Parts]

These are the things I've tried.

*Fields revealed:*
[image: Revealed fields]

*Fields Hidden:*

[image: Hidden Fields]
The results looked the same as the hidden fields. In the same document, I can see that the data from SharePoint is coming across. I was hoping at least one of those if/then constructs would properly compare the data. I've also tried using SET to put the data in a bookmark and pull it from the bookmark, but that did not work either. I can go back to those permutations if necessary, but I think I'm just missing something simple here.

Comment: Because SharePoint Document properties (and most of those under Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property have no relationship to the Document Properties accessed by that field. See https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/are-the-document-property-content-controls/3bbd131c-8970-4f71-b77f-8f10d55e6ecb. This is another example of confusing names/terms from Microsoft. By the way, this question is off-topic here because it is not a programming question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Sorry, wrong site. Your addbalance reference helped explain some things. The second link referred to the mac version not having quick parts. I'm not sure how it applies. You'd think Microsoft would take advantage of even more branding opportunities and clearly delineate between doc property and document property.

Comment: The thing is, some, but not all, of the Quick Parts document properties are linked to document properties called upon by the DocProperty field. For non-SharePoint, things like Title, Author, and Company are all in both categories.

Comment: Here is the link I intended to give: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/xml-location-of-document-properties-in-quick-parts/589d1c93-4c44-4ba4-9594-84632f182f3f again, though, this does not deal with SharePoint properties directly. See also: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html  If you see this name confusion as problematic, try text box or variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @jonsson, My test document has [Branch Approver] earlier in the document. The sample I provided was done in a later page. I did not want to mess with what I had done earlier. Since this is a template for generating documents, there's never any value in [Branch Approver] when I'm editing the codes. It gets populated from the SharePoint list. In that case, I can see the value from the SharePoint list appear in the first occurrence of [Branch Approver] outside of any If field. The data does not seem to appear when it's in the If field.

Comment: This https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287199/how-to-use-document-properties-from-sharepoint-in-conditional-if-statements shows a potential workaround along with a link to a useful explanation as to why DocProperty is not the same as Document Property. The workaround given suggests making a bookmark of the SharePoint imputed Document Property. However, when I select [Branch Approver] after it has been inserted from Quick Parts > Document Property, the bookmark icon is grayed out. I can get the bookmark icon to become available if I include text before/after [Branch Approver].

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I ended up adding logic to the workflow that generates the document, changing the approval lines to generic lines in the SharePoint library and the document template instead of role based and writing moderately complex if/then/else statements to fill them.